# Get child nodes values of an xml file with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an xml file that looks like this :

```
<Factory>
<Limits>
  <Point X="92" Y="489"/>
  <Point X="570" Y="487"/>
  <Point X="570" Y="138"/>
  <Point X="92" Y="140"/>
  <Point X="92" Y="139"/>
</Limits>
<Cells>
  <Cell>
    <Point X="358" Y="138"/>
    <Point X="361" Y="487"/>
    <Point X="570" Y="487"/>
    <Point X="570" Y="138"/>
    <Point X="358" Y="138"/>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Point X="311" Y="139"/>
    <Point X="311" Y="488"/>
    <Point X="92" Y="489"/>
    <Point X="92" Y="140"/>
    <Point X="311" Y="139"/>
  </Cell>
</Cells>
```

I'm trying to get the X and Y values of each "Point" in "Limits" (not those in "Cell") using Javascript. I saw a lot of examples with getElementByTagName, childNodes, ... but I can't figure out how to get the data I'm looking for. 
I thought something like this would work:

```
var M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Limits")[0].childNodes;
for (i=0;i<M.length;i++){
  console.log(M[i].childNodes.item(0));
}
```

I tried a few different things but I always end up either with a null value or with an error.

Is there any simple way to do what I need ?

Comment: is needs to be like this  `<Point>data</Point>`

Comment: can you use jquery solution??

Comment: Yes, I could use jquery.

Comment: @ubercooluk Sadly the xml is generated by another application and I can't change the way it's made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the attributes. With javascript:

```
M[i].getAttribute("X");
```

with jQuery:

```
M[i].attr("X");
```

Comment: Thx, getAttribute works on M[i] but not on M[i].childNodes[j]. Any idea why ?

Comment: Because there are no childNodes. M[i] is the "Point" tag, and it has no children.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Thing is now I get the "getAttribute is not a function" error (using firefox). Edit : Nvm, it is firefox related, I had to add a M[i].nodeType == 1 condition it now it works fine !

Comment: Done, except for the vote up since I need a bit more reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Limits");
for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < M[i].childNodes.length; j++){
      console.log(M[i].childNodes[j].getAttribute('X'));
      console.log(M[i].childNodes[j].getAttribute('Y'));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I try this it gives me an error :TypeError: M[i].childNodes[j].getAttribute is not a function (I'm using firefox)